# Titanium hide status bar

Tags: titanium, orientation, ios7, statusbar

I'm doing an application for Android and IOS in Titanium. The problem is that when I load the app the status bar is shown, whereas if I rotate the simulator (ipad simulator with ios 7) to landscape the status bar has been hidden.

How can I hide the status bar since the beginning? or show it always?

I've tried with this simple app:

```
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');

//
// create base UI tab and root window
//
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Tab 1',
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    fullscreen : true
});

var label1 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    color:'#999',
    text:'I am Window 1',
    font:{fontSize:20,fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'},
    textAlign:'center',
    width:'auto'
});

win1.add(label1);

win1.open();
```

I'm using sdk 3.1.2, because, with 3.1.3 some rotation things I have in the application doesn't work. I want to lock a view to allow only to rotate in portrait mode and the rest of the views to allow to rotate to all orientations.

I do it:

I put for the first view:

```
Titanium.UI.orientation = Titanium.UI.PORTRAIT;
appWindow.orientationModes = [Titanium.UI.PORTRAIT];
```

and then, when I load other view, I put:

```
appWindow.orientationModes = [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT];
```

Maybe is there any other way to do this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

To hide your statusbar

```js
 var appWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
     fullscreen: true,
     ...
 });
```

should work. Things have changed a lot since iOS7, especially when it comes to status bars.

Please find more info in the [iOS 7 Migration Guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/iOS_7_Migration_Guide-section-37533766_iOS7MigrationGuide-DeprecatedAPIs)

Comment: I've tried to do it. I update the question with an example that doesn't work for me. Thanks

Comment: Sure, so the status bar did not disappear?

Comment: Have you tried setting  UIStatusBarHidden to true in tiapp.xml?

Comment: I have this in tiapp.xml     <statusbar-hidden>true</statusbar-hidden>
    <fullscreen>true</fullscreen> Do you refer to this?

Comment: Yes, exactly... hmm, sorry I don't have any ideas left... Could be a bug of 3.1.2 with iOS7...

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much. Maybe it's a bug. The problem is that I didn't know how to manage allow some orientation in some views in 3.1.3

Comment: You can set orientationModes on every window individually, you don't need to set the parent for this, that should work for 3.1.3 too.

Answer (score 0):

just change statusbar-hidden true in tiapp.xml and add fullscreen="true" on every window tag of xml file.